# How to get list of ALL network adapters?

Tags: c#

For example, this code doesn't returns disconnected ppp/3G modem adapters(thats all I need):

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) 
{ 
    value = nic.Name; 
}
```

I searched over all the net, on most programing languages, but not found how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are not listed because when it is not active/connected it is not actually a network adapter until after it is connected.

When Inactive, I think it could be considered system configuration more then anything else.

I tried on my machine a few simple tests with a manually defined PPPoE connection as well as an LTE Data Stick Connection and a VPN to my Home server. All of these types of Network adapters behave that way.

You may want to try finding a way to list all "Dial-Up" style connections. (dont know myself how to do this)

**EDIT**

The Location of Dial-up connections is in multiple locations in text files...

User Specific Path Example On Windows 7

C:\Users\darren\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk     (File "rasphone.pbk" )

All Users

C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk     (File "rasphone.pbk" )

If I pen in notepad In my system under all users I see something like this for my LTE defined connection...

```
[LTE]
Encoding=1
PBVersion=1
Type=1
AutoLogon=0
...

[PPPoE]
Encoding=1
PBVersion=1
Type=5
AutoLogon=0
```

It's basically an INI file.

Comment: Please mark as "answer" if good. It helps everyone using the system to know the question was resolved. I have benifit greatly using this site from others.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the network adapters (Even those hidden or not connected) by using Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration. Make sure if you use the code below you are including System.Management.

Here is a quick example of how to throw those in a list then iterate through it to get their names.

```
public static IEnumerable<ManagementObject> GetAllAdaptors() {
    var tempList = new List<ManagementObject>();

    ManagementObjectCollection moc = 
        new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration").GetInstances();

    foreach(ManagementObject obj in moc) {
        tempList.Add(obj);
    }

    return tempList;
}
```

The above returns a list of all of your network adapters. Tet get the names all you have to do is iterate over the list as shown below.

```
foreach(ManagementObject obj in GetAllAdapters()) {
    var name = obj["Caption"];
}
```

This will get you all of the adapters, hidden, disconnected, connected. Basically all the ones that will show up in device manager with "Show Hidden" checked.

Comment: Side note: returning an `IEnumerable<ManagementObject>` seems a better option in this context, to disallow manually removing/adding new adapters.

Comment: Yup, I'll adjust the post accordingly.